# Help interpreting short / truncated calibration curve

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, validation, unbalanced-classes, calibration

How is the "shortness" of the curve interpreted? I have seen studies that just crop this plot and declare "good calibration," but is it?  The classifier never predicts above 0.6 in either the training or testing data.  The classes are imbalanced, by the way: might this have something to do with the fact that $P(X|Y) \propto  P(Y|X)P(X)$ and $P(X)$ is very low?

[image: cc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method appears reasonably calibrated up through 0.6, but you don't know much for higher predicted probabilities...looks like your model just isn't very confident..but it's calibrated

Comment: Suppose the model is estimating the probability of a disease.  What can we conclude based on this then?

Comment: @user99889 that it appears effective at ruling out disease but not detecting it.

Comment: could you elaborate more formally  in your answer on how you came to these conclusions? Especially examples might help.

Comment: @user99889 ok. Say your classifier predicts 5%, then, because its well calibrated you know there is a low chance of disease. However, either the algorithm or your training set do not allow a confident diagnosis (>95%) of the presence of the disease.

Comment: Aha. Ty.  But if it predicts 1% for patient A and 5% for patient B, we can say that B has a 5-fold higher risk of the disease?

Comment: @user99889 yes, because your model appears to be calibrated at the low range.